# mssql_query returns no value

Tags: php, sql-server

My app uses PHP 5.5 and SQL Server to query some records from database and displays.

This query takes around 2 minutes to execute when run on the SQL Server.

My issue is that `mssql_query()` returns NOTHING sometimes (i.e. neither resource id nor true or false).

I have a hunch that the issue is caused due to SQL Server timeout, but I am failing to prove it as I have `mssql.timeout = 300` (sec) configured in `php.ini` file.

Can anyone help me in finding the root cause please? I am new to php.

SQL query:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT 
    *
FROM table1 latest
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 successful 
ON latest.MachineVersionID = successful.MachineVersionID
 AND successful.BackupToken = (
    SELECT TOP 1 BackupToken
    FROM table1
    WHERE MachineVersionID = successful.MachineVersionID
    AND BackupState = 7 AND IsPartial = 0
    ORDER BY EndTime DESC
)
INNER JOIN table2 mv ON latest.MachineVersionID = mv.MachineVersionID
INNER JOIN table3 m ON mv.MachineID = m.MachineID
INNER JOIN table4 c ON m.ClientID = c.ClientID
WHERE latest.BackupToken = (
    SELECT TOP 1 BackupToken
    FROM table1
    WHERE MachineVersionID = latest.MachineVersionID
    ORDER BY EndTime DESC
)
AND c.PartnerID in (1,2,3,4,5,....)
ORDER BY latest.MachineVersionID

OUTPUT : Return value after executing SQL:
 at 11-09-15 04:01:02.189
```

Comment: Where is your SQl query?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/365549/5397119