# PHP script with MySQL query timing out

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, mysqli

I am having issues running a PHP script which inserts data to MySQL.  The error I get is "**504 Gateway Time - out nginx**"  When the PHP page gets stuck with this timeout 10,102 lines of data have been entered to the database.  I'm planning to insert 160,000 lines in one load of the script.

I have made my code more efficient by using a prepared statement for the SQL.
The SQL is also set up in this structure:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

I have read SO [PHP script times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961011/php-script-times-out) and [How to keep a php script from timing out because of a long mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365496/how-to-keep-a-php-script-from-timing-out-because-of-a-long-mysql-query)

I have tried adding to the start of my code but doesn't seem to make a difference:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);
```

Can anyone show me data to split dataset into chunnks and for each chunk data is inserted?

I will show the section of code that inserts to MySQL below

```
 // prepare and bind
$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (`eventID`,`location`,`date`,`barcode`,`runner`,`time`,`Run Points`,`Volunteer Points`,`Gender`, `Gender pos`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("isssssiisi", $eventID,$location,$date,$barcode,$runner,$time,$runpoints,$volpoints,$gender,$genderpos);

// set parameters and execute
for( $x=0; $x < count($array_runner); $x++ ){
    $eventID=null;
    $barcode=$array_barcode[$x];
    $runner=$array_runner[$x];
    $time=$array_time[$x];
    $runpoints=$array_score[$x];
    $volpoints=' ';
    $gender=$array_gender[$x];
    $genderpos=$array_gender_pos[$x];

    $stmt->execute();

}

$stmt->close();
$link->close();
```

I am new to working with MySQL and am looking for some guidance with this problem.

Comment: I think you have no rights to change php time limit, in this case you don't have any chance to solve this problem this way. You can split your SQL queries to separated parts

Comment: Can you run this script as a PHP CLI i.e. from the command line! There is no `max_execution_time` applied to the CLI

Comment: Thanks for your comment Peter.  Ah "no rights" is annoying, this project is only hosted on iPage on a shared server and there are no plans to use a dedicated server / VPS.  Can you provide any code that splits up the SQL in separated parts?

Answer (score 1):

`set_time_limit(0);` resets the count when it is executed. It does not change the `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` so to make it have any useful effect you would have to run it in the loop.

```
 // prepare and bind
$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (`eventID`,`location`,`date`,`barcode`,`runner`,`time`,`Run Points`,`Volunteer Points`,`Gender`, `Gender pos`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("isssssiisi", $eventID,$location,$date,$barcode,$runner,$time,$runpoints,$volpoints,$gender,$genderpos);

// set parameters and execute
for( $x=0; $x < count($array_runner); $x++ ){
    $eventID=null;
    $barcode=$array_barcode[$x];
    $runner=$array_runner[$x];
    $time=$array_time[$x];
    $runpoints=$array_score[$x];
    $volpoints=' ';
    $gender=$array_gender[$x];
    $genderpos=$array_gender_pos[$x];

    $stmt->execute();

    // every 5000 times through the loop reset the timeout
    if ( $x % 5000 == 0 ) {
        set_time_limit(30);
    }
}

$stmt->close();
$link->close();
```

Of course you can play with the value 5000 so it does the reset less often.

> From the Manual:
>
> When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero. In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25 seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.

Comment: set_time_limit has nothing to do with 504 Gateway Time - out **nginx**

Comment: @YourCommonSense Well it can be caused by a `max_execution_time` being exceeded as far as I know! ALthough I admit there are lots of other reasons as well

Comment: thanks @RiggsFolly for this code, I have tried using set_time_limit() within the loop but the script is still stuck at 10,102 lines of data.

Comment: @Jeanclaude Bad Luck, Sorry it was not your issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly no worries, I'm trying the same code but with a longer time limit.  So I've just run the code with set_time_limit(360) and it has pulled through 15,374 lines of data before cutting out.  This is the biggest amount of data i have inserted into the database with only one run through!  On another note the guys at iPage web hosting have told me that I can't use set_time_limit() whilst on a shared hosting server.  So maybe I don't have much control but the script has just pulled through this much data with the code you mentioned.  Thanks again

Comment: Looks like you are going to have to break the input data into multiple small bites

Answer (score 0):

If you are using query inside a loop with so large number of rows it would definitely stuck.

The best way I can suggest is simply handle all the data to be inserted  in a PHP string and then fire a single query to insert data.

Let me elaborate

```
$data_to_insert = '' // will contain all data to inserted
$count = 1;
$eventID = null; // if it is null for all rows

for( $x=0; $x < count($array_runner); $x++ )
{    
    if($count == 1)  // checking if it is the first value to be inserted
    {
        $data_to_insert = "(";
        $count = 2;
    }
    else // with second value onwards
    {
        $data_to_insert = ",(" ;
    }

    $data_to_insert = $data_to_insert .   $eventID . ",";
    $data_to_insert = $data_to_insert . "'".   $barcode . "'";
    $data_to_insert = $data_to_insert . "'".   $array_runner[$x] . "'";
    $data_to_insert = ")";
}
// so in the last $data_to_insert should look like this
// $data_to_insert =  (eventid1 , 'barcode1', 'runner1'), (eventid2 , 'barcode2', 'runner2') and so on...
```

Then fire the query

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO MyGuests (`eventID`,`barcode`,`runner`)  values" . $data_to_insert);
// which would look like
// INSERT INTO MyGuests (`eventID`,`barcode`,`runner`)  values (eventid1 , 'barcode1', 'runner1'), (eventid2 , 'barcode2', 'runner2')
```

Note : 
There might be some syntax error in my code, but you get the logic here.